# CGRectMake Coordinates

Tags: objective-c, uikit, cgrectmake

I ran into a weird problem where the coordinates I am using for CGRectMake function do not seem to be correct. For example:

```
CGRect screenR = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
sWidth = screenR.size.width;
sHeight = screenR.size.height;
button.frame = CGRectMake(sWidth-50, sHeight-50, 50, 50);
```

This sizes my button to be 50x50 in size and places it correct horizontally, but the button show up in the middle of the screen vertically. I don't know what causes the vertical coordinates to show up incorrectly. Please help.

Comment: Where's the code in which you're adding the button to a view?  Are you using any sort of autolayout?  Is button part of a subview?  etc...

Comment: Where does you want to show the button exactly?

Comment: Not using autolayout, I am adding the button in storyboard and moving it programmatically. I want the button in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Is this due to difference in co-ordinates of core graphics and UI Kit? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html

Comment: I don't know. The direction of the coordinates seems to be correct as per my code, its just the vertical size of the screen seems to be larger than sHeight = screenR.size.height returns. To get my button to the bottom of the screen I am having to input sHeight+200 as the vertical coordinate

Comment: @user2303367 I'm not sure why you're going to `[UIScreen mainScreen]`. I'd always go to the `bounds` of the superview of the button (because you don't want this offset by the screen, but rather offset within a particular view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was with having that code within 'viewDidLoad'. Apparently the coordinates of the view are not completely initialized until that view appears and resulted in the weird behaviour I was describing above. Putting the code within 'viewDidAppear' solved my problem.